# Find the strategy: How to order without knowing

Tags: algorithm

Imagine: You have a group of people in a room that is completely dark. Half of the group has red t-shirts and the other half blue t-shirts. The group gets told to think about a strategy to solve the following task:

When you leave the darkroom and enter a bright room one after the other, you should organize yourself in a line that is split in a red and blue half. You can only see the current state of the line but, you do not know your own color. Now think about a strategy how everyone that leaves the darkroom should follow to achieve the described line.

Have fun

Comment: This is a classic puzzle so I'm almost sure a version of it must have been asked here before, but my search attempts have not been able to find it.

Comment: I found a possible duplicate: [Red and Blue in the Chocolate Fountain Room](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26251/red-and-blue-in-the-chocolate-fountain-room)